# NGINX fails to bind to Unix socket

Tags: linux, nginx, unix-socket

I'm trying to get Nginx to listen on a Unix socket. I need it for something else which fails to connect to the socket because the permissions are too strict. However when I try to change the permissions on the socket Nginx fails to start up again with an error `bind() to unix:/path/here failed (98: Unknown error)`. At first I though it's because I set the wrong permissions but the same thing happens even when I set the permissions to `777`. Later I tried changing the owner of the socket and changing it back to the original and I got the same error. So I'm under the impression that I can't modify the socket in any way. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Assuming that `98` is an error code in above, `perror 98` says `OS error code  98:  Address already in use`

Comment: You are right! I was so focused on finding out what's wrong with the socket itself that I didn't notice that nginx actually won't start at all while the old socket exists. I'll just have to find some way to delete the old socket.

Comment: @FilipTimko if your system uses SystemD (most likely anyway), the easiest you can do is setting up your socket in the same location as your nginx service's `RuntimeDirectory=`. This will ensure that the old socket is cleaned up. Check current value for this directive with `systemctl cat nginx`, and if it's not present, create it by running `systemctl edit nginx` and creating override file, etc.